# How to move the Camera Based on the mouse's x position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a 2d game, the background you are in is wider then the camera can see. I want to make it so that the Camera moves on the x axis exponentially based on how high or low the value of (Input.mouse.position.x) is. I was searching for an answer to this most of last night and no dice. Any help is appreciated :) I'm very new with c# and unity so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: it would be nice if you tell us what lib, framework, are you using to develop your game

Comment: Do you already have some code that moves the camera? Do you mean exponentially as in the mathematical function or could it be a linear relationship between the mouse position and the camera?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Everything is stock, just using the unity editor with visual studio.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't have any code for the camera yet since I don't think it will need anything else besides this one effect. Also by exponentially I basically just mean that the further the mouse is towards the end of the canvas the faster the camera looks at that area. Sorry for being unclear :)

Comment: @maksy Perhaps you could google for "unity 2d move camera with mouse" to see if any of those results apply to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand correctly what you want to do. I would say:

Take the width of your background and divide by the screen width and multiply with mouseX. Then place your camera on the result. Mabye you have to add a fix value depending on your camera angle, that you cant see the edge of your background.

```
float result = (backgroundWidth / ScreenWidth) * MouseX;
```

Use this for your camera position and you should be fine, as long as you have your background at 0,0,0 world location. If not you can at this to your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, what you want is to make the camera follow the player’s x position. Use this code :-

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;            
    }

}
```

It will make the camera follow your player on the x-axis position. If you want any other help please let me know. I am always there for help.